# Redirect output to dynamic IP and change port

Tags: linux, iptables, port, dynamic, dnat

I have an application that needs to communication with two external hosts.  For various reasons the host has now become a dynamic IP address.  Since iptables communications via IP, simply using a straight DNAT won't do.  I can change the hostname/IP address for the two external connection hosts in the application.
So for one of the hosts I could set a bogus IP, 1.1.1.1. It *seems* ipset may help.

What I need to do is something like

iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 1.1.1.1 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination -m set --set externalhostip_port

Comment: Use a VPN tunnel.

Comment: Certainly that would work.  Setting up a VPN infrastructure is a good bit more complicated than rewriting packets if a rule or 2 will do it.

Comment: it's a lot less work than constantly changing IP addresses

Comment: Not really.  It's trivial for have a cron job change the address in a table in ipsets

Comment: Ya know, I haven't had an opportunity to use wireguard yet- and I never did care for OpenVPN, so I'm giving that a shot.